# Leibniz integral rule for the Airy function.

Tags: integration, leibniz-integral-rule, airy-functions

We recall that the Airy function is (well) defined by:

$\text{Ai}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_0^\infty \cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3} + xt\right) dt$

I want to apply the theorem of differentiation under the integral sign (Leibniz rule), but I can't find the dominating functions.

The derivative we consider is given by
$ -((t + x^2) \sin(tx + \frac{x^3}{3})) $.

Comment: You can consider it's analytic extension. The real part of the integrand has an integrable tail on the contour of integration(Of the form $e^{-t^{3}}$) which would suffice .